# Precision of the quotient of two double precision numbers

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

Let's say I want to calculate numerically the first derivative of f(x) = cos(x) at x = pi/2. df/dx = -sin(x), hence  is df/dx=-1. For this I use the simplest formula:

df/dx = (f(x+h)-f(x))/h + O(h).

Here O(h) is the error, which is proportional to h and therefore, mathematically O(h) goes to zero as h goes to zero. I understand that in a computer things are different.

Should I expect that if I am using double precision, which should give me between 15 and 17 decimal significant digits, I should be able to approach the exact result df/dx = -1.0 by ~10^-15? I.e. should I find (df/dx)_numerical + 1.0 ~ 10^-15?

This is what I find for different values of h:

h values:

```
[0.0001, 1e-05, 1e-06, 1e-07, 1e-08, 1e-09, 1e-10]
```

(df/dx)_numerical:

```
[-0.9999999983332231,
-0.9999999999898844,
-0.9999999999175667,
-1.0000000005838656,
-0.999999993922529,
-1.000000082740371,
-1.000000082740371]
```

Is this expected? Why? Why is the best result obtained for h = 10^-5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating derivatives by using finite differencing is prone to [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). The issue is the context in which you're subtracting, not the division you're doing. Basically, `cos(x)-cos(x+delta)` will work okay when `cos(x)` and `cos(x+delta)` are both nearly zero... but as they get away from zero (and yet are still close to *each other*), the precision of the result will drop dramatically. At a certain point, the increase in accuracy from using a smaller delta will be offset by the decrease in precision caused by loss of significance. For you, it looks like that happened around 1e-5, but that's not fundamental (and in that region, the error will tend to bounce around a lot).

A lot has been written about how to do numerically stable finite differencing, but the number one rule is "don't get too greedy with the smallness of your differences". For more in-depth (and less vague) information, I can recommend Forman Acton's *Numerical Methods That (Usually) Work*.

### EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to mention the most important bit. The loss of significance in the numerator is important, but the loss of significance in `x+h` is even more so. And that part's actually pretty easy to fix.

As `x` gets bigger, the approximation of `x+h` gets worse (again, loss of significance). Basically, the step size you're using for evaluation isn't matching the step size in the denominator. But! Since you don't really care about the *exact* value of `h`, you can just figure out what `h` value you ended up using after `x+h` got rounded, and use that in the denominator as well. Essentially, you calculate `x2=x+h`, then `h'=x2-x`. The calculation of `h'` is exact when `x >> h` (Sterbenz's Theorem), eliminating that particular loss of significance.

Example code:

```
import math

def calcDerivAt_orig(f, x, h):
    x1 = x
    x2 = x+h
    y1 = f(x1)
    y2 = f(x2)
    return (y2-y1)/h

def calcDerivAt_fixed(f, x, h):
    x1 = x
    x2 = x+h
    y1 = f(x1)
    y2 = f(x2)
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

for h in [0.0001, 1e-05, 1e-06, 1e-07, 1e-08, 1e-09, 1e-10]:
    dOrig = calcDerivAt_orig(math.cos, math.pi/2, h)
    origErr = abs(-1 - dOrig)
    dFixed = calcDerivAt_fixed(math.cos, math.pi/2, h)
    fixedErr = abs(-1 - dFixed)
    print("h = {}: origErr = {}, fixedErr = {}".format(h, origErr, fixedErr))
```

which produces:

```
h = 0.0001: origErr = 1.66677693869e-09, fixedErr = 1.66666680457e-09
h = 1e-05: origErr = 1.01155750443e-11, fixedErr = 1.6666779068e-11
h = 1e-06: origErr = 8.24332824223e-11, fixedErr = 1.66644475996e-13
h = 1e-07: origErr = 5.83865622517e-10, fixedErr = 1.55431223448e-15
h = 1e-08: origErr = 6.07747097092e-09, fixedErr = 0.0
h = 1e-09: origErr = 8.27403709991e-08, fixedErr = 0.0
h = 1e-10: origErr = 8.27403709991e-08, fixedErr = 0.0
```

Not bad at all. Of course, we're cheating with our choice of `x=pi/2`, because `cos(x)` is close to zero around there; at `x=1.5` or something, you'll still see a ballooning in the error as `h` shrinks, from the loss of significance I originally described:

```
h = 0.0001: origErr = 3.53519750529e-06, fixedErr = 3.5351976152e-06
h = 1e-05: origErr = 3.53675653653e-07, fixedErr = 3.53669118991e-07
h = 1e-06: origErr = 3.52831192041e-08, fixedErr = 3.53651797846e-08
h = 1e-07: origErr = 4.03034106089e-09, fixedErr = 3.44793649187e-09
h = 1e-08: origErr = 5.5453325265e-09, fixedErr = 5.1691428915e-10
h = 1e-09: origErr = 7.21702790862e-08, fixedErr = 1.03628251535e-08
h = 1e-10: origErr = 1.6659127966e-08, fixedErr = 6.58739718329e-08
```